# creating a convex hull of irregular shape

Tags: r-sp, spatstat

I have coordinates from two transect lines and want to create a convex hull around them to use for point pattern analysis. However, so far my convex hull is a rectangle and I don't know how to make it an irregular shape so that it just encompasses the two lines.

Here is a reproducible example:
Here are my x and y coordinates

```
X <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
Y <- c(5,5,5,5,5,7,7,7,7,7)
```

I combine them into a dataframe with columns labeled X and Y:

```
TransectLines <- as.data.frame(cbind(X,Y))
```

Here are the two transect lines plotted:

```
plot(TransectLines)
```

[image: transect lines]

I made a convex hull using the X and Y coordinates:

```
twoTransects.chull <- convexhull.xy(x = TransectLines$X, y = TransectLines$Y)
```

And plotted the convex hull:

```
plot(twoTransects.chull)
```

[image: hull]

And plotted the transect line points on top of it:

```
points(TransectLines$X,TransectLines$Y)
```

[image: hull with points]

I would like the hull to wrap around the transect lines only, instead of being a rectangle. Is that possible?

Comment: The given rectangle **is** the convex hull of that point set as defined mathematically. How do you want it to wrap around the points?

Comment: I see what you're saying. I guess I want the command to generate 2 convex hulls, each wrapping tightly around a transect line. The reason is that if I used the rectangular hull for my point pattern analysis, the analysis would indicate that my points are clumped simply because they are in straight lines.

Comment: Do you have information indicating which transect each point belongs to? Then it should be straightforward to split the data according to this and calculate the convex hull for each. I'm not sure this approach makes sense from a statistical point of view, but that is a long discussion involving the research question of interest etc.

Comment: Thanks! I do have that information for my real dataset so will keep that in mind as an option. I ended up creating a buffer around the transects using buffer() in the Raster package, which produced a polygon object that wraps tightly around my points. I used that to create the owin object I needed for point pattern analysis as an alternative to the convex hull.

Comment: FYI: If you need a buffer region in `spatstat` have a look at `dilation()`.